# Question about add_image_size()

Tags: images

I created an image size:

```
add_image_size('slider', 1920, 1080, true);
```

Now, i thought hard cropping meant that WordPress would zoom into the picture until it obtains that size and proportion no matter what.

Well, if User enters a vertical image, say 784x1200, What WordPress is doing is getting me an 784x1080 image, so it ignores the asked width because it matches height first??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's check the behavior of cropping. According to [code reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size/):

> 1. If false (default), images will be scaled, not cropped.
>
>    2. If an array in the form of `array( x_crop_position, y_crop_position ):`
>
>       - x_crop_position accepts `left`, `center`, or `right`.
>       - y_crop_position accepts `top`, `center`, or `bottom`. Images will be cropped to the specified dimensions within the defined crop
>           area.
>    3. If true, images will be cropped to the specified dimensions using
>         center positions.

So, here's what's gonna happen when you set the dimensions to 1920x1080 and then upload an image:

- If both width and height of the image are larger, the image will be cropped as 1920/1080 (Or 16/9) by its center and then resized to 1920x1080.
- If one of the image's dimensions are larger than 1920 or 1080, then the larger side will be cropped to match the appropriate side, and the other side will be untouched.
- If none of the sides are larger than 1920 or 1080, no thumbnail will be generated.

Answer (score 1):

WordPress can't make images *bigger* when they crop. If an image is smaller than a given image size, the image won't be made for that size. For example, if you upload - 200x200 image, a 150x150 thumbnail will be made, but a 300x300 medium size won't be. If you upload a 400x100 image, a 300x75 medium image will be made, but the thumbnail will only resize and crop the axis that is big enough, you'll get. 150x100 thumbnail.